# Multiple Approval Processes with same entry criteria

Tags: force.com, approval-process

What will happen if there are 2 approval processes on same object having same entry criteria ?

Will both fire or anyone one of them will fire ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one approval process will be executed and which one will be executed will depend on the Process Order.

Comment: What do you mean by Process Order ?

Comment: You can define execution order of approval processes. You can decide which approval process should be executed first. that order is known as Process Order. If approval process enters in one criteria then it doesn't check any other criteria.